# npm ERR! when trying to install bcrypt on npm nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, bcrypt

I want to install bcrypt in my node js with the command `"npm install bcrypt"` but it doesn't work.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but still the error

any suggestions that can help? thank you

> `PS E:\OneDrive\Documents\log&reg\logresjwt> npm install bcrypt`
>
> ```
> > bcrypt@5.0.1 install E:\OneDrive\Documents\log&reg\logresjwt\node_modules\bcrypt
> > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> 'reg\logresjwt\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
>   throw err;
>   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'E:\OneDrive\Documents\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp'       
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)       
>     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
>   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   requireStack: []
> }
> npm WARN logresjwt@1.0.0 No description
> npm WARN logresjwt@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.1 install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-28T16_18_13_219Z-debug.log
>
> PS E:\OneDrive\Documents\log&reg\logresjwt> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build 
> node-pre-gyp : The term 'node-pre-gyp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should install node-gyp globally on your pc.

> sudo npm install -g node-gyp
> then
> npm install bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run this:

```
npm uninstall bcrypt

npm install bcrypt
```

That works for me.

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the bcrypt module dependency node-gyp. I suggest you use a library bcryptjs which has no dependencies and more downloads.

```
npm i bcryptjs --save
```

and dont forget to uninstall

```
npm uninstall bcrypt --save
```

On top of that brcypt has more dependecies like python 2.x. This will be also an issue on deployment also. It is better to use libraries with no dependencies.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs